# Saving UIColor, UIFont and NSDictionary to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios5, nsuserdefaults

In my application, I have some color settings, font settings and a Dictionary containing application specific objects ( these objects are classes with properties, which are private to application ). The color settings and font settings are sort of public settings for the application. I would like to save them to **NSUserDefaults** but it will show any of the font or color properly, so I am saving them using this line of code

```
// reading the value
NSData *foregroundcolorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foregroundcolor"];
UIColor *foregndcolor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:foregroundcolorData];

// setting the default values
NSData *foregndcolorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:foregndcolorData forKey:@"foregroundcolor"];

// saving the changes, by putting everything in a dictionary called "preferences"
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:preferences];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I decided to put every settings in the application UI. In order for the code above to work, I need to add a "settings bundle" file to the application project. This causes the application to put an entry in the device/system settings panel. It is empty, Since I don't set any application configuration details in the settings bundle file.

How can I get around this problem ?

Comment: Why don't you just make a custom object with the properties you want to save and then archive/unarchive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom holder object

```
@interface HolderObject : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *xColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont *xFont;

@end

@implementation PTextHolder

@synthesize xColor, xFont;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
    [encoder encodeObject:xColor forKey:@"xColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:xFont forKey:@"xFont"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder 
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        self.xColor = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"xColor"];
        self.xFont = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"xFont"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem is... how will I save the defauls ? The user needs a way to set the settings to a default state if he messes it up. :)

Comment: You'd write this object to file at the beginning of the application, then let the user edit it. If he screws up you can do `objectName = [/*unarchive method*/]` and you'll get back an unedited version.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that way, but I was feeling it is kind of a dirty way to do it. :-)